# Custom JS Object not parsing correctly

Tags: javascript, oop

The following object is built based on the examples in "Principles of Object-Oriented Programming in JavaScript"  by Nicholas Zakas.  However there is something I cannot glean wrong with the syntax.  When I attempt to load this into the browser I get an error in the console:  "ReferenceError: owner_idx is not defined"

Anyone have an idea about how this could be repaired?

```
function Editor() {
    Object.defineProperty(this, "program_idx", {
        get: function() {
            return program_idx;
        },
        set: function(newVal) {
            program_idx = newVal;
        },
        enumerable: true,
        configurable: true
    });

    Object.defineProperty(this, "owner_idx", {
        get: function() {
            return owner_idx;
        },
        set: function(newVal) {
            owner_idx = newVal;
        },
        enumerable: true,
        configurable: true
    });
};
```

Comment: You realize you're assigning to the global scope, right?

Comment: I had missed that the storage vars were being defaulted to the global context.

Answer (score 2):

Well, "owner_idx is not defined". Why don't you define it?

```
function Editor() {

    var program_idx, owner_idx; 

    Object.defineProperty(this, "program_idx", {
        get: function() {
            return program_idx;
        },
        set: function(newVal) {
            program_idx = newVal;
        },
        enumerable: true,
        configurable: true
    });

    Object.defineProperty(this, "owner_idx", {
        get: function() {
            return owner_idx;
        },
        set: function(newVal) {
            owner_idx = newVal;
        },
        enumerable: true,
        configurable: true
    });
};

var e = new Editor();
e.owner_idx = "foo";
console.log(e.owner_idx);
```

**HOWEVER** you don't need accessor methods if your sole intent is to get/set property values (without transforming them before storing/retrieving, or making a change in their value affect other properties). Regular properties would work just fine.

Comment: Well, the program_idx was also not defined, without raising an error. I assumed there is some subtle syntaxy error in my model. JSLint had no complaints at all. Strange. Thanks!